# Fullscreen Fragment smooth animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

**Goal:**

I have an app that uses a single activity that manages multiple fragments. One of those fragments needs to be fullscreen with the system UI hidden (top and navigation bars), but the others need the system UI visible. The goal is to achieve smoothing animations when entering and exiting the fullscreen fragment.

**Problem:**

The problem is that the animation appears jittery because I'm entering and exiting fullscreen (immersive) mode at the same time as animating the fragment transition. I'm setting the immersive mode from the fullscreen fragment `onCreateView` using:

```
int newUiOptions = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
newUiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
```

and I reset it when exiting the fragment using

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried moving the point where I enable (`onCreateView`, `onResume`) and disable (`onDetach`, `onBackClicked`, `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`) around, but there's always a UI jump when the fullscreen mode is enabled/disabled, either in the fullscreen fragment or in the main fragment.

I've tried using a fullscreen DialogFragment instead of regular Fragment, but that too has a jumpy animation on main fragment when exiting the dialog fullscreen fragment.

The closest I've got is making the whole application use fullscreen (immersive) mode, then in MainActivity I get the insets of system top and navigation bars and apply them to fragment container view in main activity layout. I show the system UI while keeping the app fullscreen, which is drawn over my UI, but that is taken care of using the insets. I exposed a method of setting the fragment container margins, so that the fullscreen fragment can set them to 0 and hide the system UI to make it really fullscreen, while I set margins to insets and show the system UI for all other fragments. But this seems like a long and hacky way of doing things.
This was done by resetting the UI like this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

in the MainActivity on start and also when exiting the fullscreen fragment. But even this makes a tiny jump when changing the fragment container margins, so I guess the only way to make it really smooth is to apply the insets not to fragment container in the MainActivity, but instead in root view of each fragment.

Is there really no (easy/clean) way to tell the android that I want one fragment in fullscreen and the others with system UI visible and make the OS animate it accordingly?